# Show/hide sidebar toolbar item position

Tags: macos, swiftui

[image]
[image]

I want the toolbar icon to remain next to the close, minimize, and maximize dots at all times. How do I do it in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, you just have to not use the default `ToolbarItem`

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
        Button(action: {
            toggleSidebar()
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
        }
    )
}
```

Instead just use a simple Image:

```
.toolbar {
    Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
        .onTapGesture {
            toggleSidebar()
        }
}
```

[image]